# Perl hashes: I don't understand why and what is going on

Tags: perl

I have the code below:

```
$data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{tb}->{'2|LIABILITIES|24974-000'} = 0
        if ( !defined( $data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{tb}->{'2|LIABILITIES|24974-000'} ) ); # advisory    

$data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{tb}->{'2|LIABILITIES|24975-000'} = 0
        if ( !defined( $data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{tb}->{'2|LIABILITIES|24975-000'} ) ); # operating         

$data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{tb}->{'1|ASSETS|11150-800'} = 0
        if ( !defined($data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{tb}->{'1|ASSETS|11150-800'} ) );       # change in market    

$data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{tb}->{'1|ASSETS|11150-000'} = 0
        if ( !defined($data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{tb}->{'1|ASSETS|11150-000'} ) );       # book value    

$data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{change}->{'3|INCOME|46515-000'} = 0
        if ( !defined($data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{change}->{'3|INCOME|46515-000'} ) );   # dividend_income
```

I don't understand what this code does. Maybe it connects hash `$data` key `reports` with hash `$arg` key `port`, hash `tb` and so on

Comment: read this http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html

Comment: I'd recommend [Mark's very short tutorial about references](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Answer (score 5):

All it's doing is setting some nested hash values to zero if they are currently `undef`. It can be written much more cleanly

This code is equivalent. It makes these changes

- Extract the root hash reference to a variable `$tb`
- Remove unnecessary indirection operators `->`
- Make use of the *defined-or assignment operator* `//=`

  `a //= b` means `a = b unless defined a`

I hope this is clearer for you

```
my $tb = $data->{reports}{ $args->{port} }{tb};

$tb->{tb}{'2|LIABILITIES|24974-000'} //= 0; # advisory    
$tb->{tb}{'2|LIABILITIES|24975-000'} //= 0; # operating         
$tb->{tb}{'1|ASSETS|11150-800'}      //= 0; # change in market    
$tb->{tb}{'1|ASSETS|11150-000'}      //= 0; # book value 
$tb->{change}{'3|INCOME|46515-000'}  //= 0; # dividend_income
```

Comment: @Borodon,@simbabque, your explanation is perfect. Could you please tell me where can I read about all this? The website is better, if it exists.

Comment: Does it makes any difference if my program is for WINODWS?

Comment: @osamuyl No. Not in this case. As long as you're using Perl 5.10+ (when `//` was introduced to the public).

Comment: @osamuyl: Perl is distributed with a full set of documentation that may be accessed using the `perldoc` command-line utility. It's also available on line at [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/). There is a contents page at [`perldoc perl`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl.html) and all the operators, including `//=`, are documented at [`perldoc perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html), specifially the [*Assignment Operators* section](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators)

Answer (score 4):

I have re-indented your code and replaced the `if !defined` with `unless`. I have also removed the parenthesis to make it more easy to understand what's going on.

```
# advisory
$data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{tb}->{'2|LIABILITIES|24974-000'} = 0
    unless defined $data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{tb}->{'2|LIABILITIES|24974-000'};

# operating         
$data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{tb}->{'2|LIABILITIES|24975-000'} = 0
    unless defined $data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{tb}->{'2|LIABILITIES|24975-000'};

# change in market    
$data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{tb}->{'1|ASSETS|11150-800'} = 0
    unless defined $data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{tb}->{'1|ASSETS|11150-800'};

# book value 
$data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{tb}->{'1|ASSETS|11150-000'} = 0
    unless defined $data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{tb}->{'1|ASSETS|11150-000'};

# dividend_income  
$data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{change}->{'3|INCOME|46515-000'} = 0
    unless defined $data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb}->{change}->{'3|INCOME|46515-000'};
```

It now reads a lot better, because it's almost English.

There is a *postfix* `if` command in Perl that means *run this line **if** the following is true*. The `unless` I replaced is the same, just a *if not*.

This is really just one operation repeated five times with different values. It looks in the `$data` data structure if a certain value is defined, which means it's not `undef`. If that is not the case, it puts a default value of `0` there.

---

The whole code could be made way easier to read like this:

```
my $tb = $data->{reports}->{ $args->{port} }->{tb};
$tb->{tb}->{'2|LIABILITIES|24974-000'} //= 0;    # advisory
$tb->{tb}->{'2|LIABILITIES|24975-000'} //= 0;    # operating
$tb->{tb}->{'1|ASSETS|11150-800'}      //= 0;    # change in market
$tb->{tb}->{'1|ASSETS|11150-000'}      //= 0;    # book value
$tb->{change}->{'3|INCOME|46515-000'}  //= 0;    # dividend_income
```

This means the same thing. I first took the part of the data structure that was deep down and assigned it to a variable. Because these are all references, that's not a copy, but rather like a pointer. [The `//=` operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators) means *assign the right-hand-side value to the left-hand-side value if that value is not defined*. It was [added in Perl 5.9.0](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl590delta.html#Defined-or-operators). Now your code is a lot more readable.

Comment: Hah! I've just posted your last section as an answer, including variable naming. Sorry. You're not quite right though, as the last assignment uses `->{tb}->{change}->` instead of `->{tb}->{tb}->`

Comment: So, in the last case we even don't need if !define and/or unless?

Comment: @Borodin indeed. I didn't see that part. Too many arrows. Thanks for pointing it out. Your explanation is way more concise though.

Comment: @osamuyl the `//=` combines that into a simple operator.

Comment: @simbabque: By all accounts lengthier posts gather more votes, so while concise should be a *good thing*, it's not an advantage on Stack Overflow. One of its many anomalies!

Comment: @simbabque: I had no idea your first language was not English—you write very well. What is your native language? I have a chronic guilt that English-speaking nations have become lazy with language and require other nationalities to fall in line. And unfortunately I am disabled and unable to travel far, but do send your holiday snaps!

Comment: Guys, please let me know the website, where I can read EVERYTING ABOUT THBIS.

Comment: @Borodin German. That's unfortunate, Perl conferences are a lot of fun, and [great to meet like-minded people](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303313/1331451).

Comment: @osamuyl you can always read the Perl documentation at http://perldoc.perl.org/. Make sure to pick the right version on the left. If you don't know your Perl version, run `perl -v`.

Comment: I HAVE PERL 5.18.4. All I can find on perldoc.perl.org? BTW, my Perl program is for WINDOWS. Does it makes any difference?

Comment: @osamuyl Unfortunately there's no single page (at least none I know of) but several: [data structures](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#HASHES-OF-HASHES), [`//`, `//=`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or), [arrow operator (3rd bullet)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html#Using-References). Perl 5.18 is ok. It's not the very latest (5.24) but new enough. And Windows makes no difference with regard to the current issue.

Comment: @osamuyl for 5.18.4 you should refer to the 5.18.2 docs. I don't know why they don't have the .4 version there, but the [perldelta](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5184delta.html) shows that there were not a lot of things changed, and that 5.18.3 was broken. You can also use the `perldoc` command on the command line. But that kind of requires a bit of an overview of how the documentation is structured.

Comment: @simbabque All non-even version numbers should be avoided because, well, they are odd. ;-) They are debugging or sth. versions and it's better to stick to the even ones (5.10, .12, .14, ...). I believe this is true also for the 3rd digits (the "4" in "5.18.4"). (How are they called? Tiny?)

Comment: @PerlDog the odd thing is for mayor releases, not for minor ones as far as I know. Those are development releases. Since the language is Perl 5, the first sub-version is the mayor, and the second sub-version is the minor release.

Comment: @simbabque Ah, ok. Im never sure about the terminology. But while we were talking about languages: _odd_ has two different meanings: _uneven_ and _strange_. I just tend to avoid the strange ones ;-)

Comment: Guys, thanks a lot for your help and explanation. It is very difficult to get code from somebody else, who is not with the company and try to understand it.

Comment: To be clear, the odd/even number for development/production versions of Perl only applies to the **second** part of the version number. The current version is 5.24.0. If a bugfix version is released, that will be 5.24.1 - and that will be a production version. 5.25.x is the current development version.

Comment: @osamuyl the first thing I usually do when I have to understand a block of code that makes no sense is indent it properly. [Perltidy](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Perl-Tidy/bin/perltidy) is great for that. I've set that up in my IDE as a keyboard shortcut. Besides that, you'll just have to get more practice I believe. It's not like we learn all this stuff by heart (though some maybe do;)), but rather knowledge comes with experience.

Comment: @Borodin now I'm getting downvotes, probably because the bottom of my answer looks like your answer, which is on top now. It's not always the longer answers that win... ;)

Comment: @PerlDog: *"How are they called? Tiny?"* I think you're looking for "minor"